# Run PyGame program without booting to Desktop Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I am using the PiTFT display for the Raspberry Pi, and I want to run my PyGame (Python) program without booting to the Desktop.

The reason I want to do this is because it will mean less RAM usage, and that is pretty important on a Raspberry Pi.
This has been asked before, but none of the answers are up to date, or else never worked in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear what problem you're having, but this should be fairly straightforward.

I add this at the top of my pygame scripts when using the PiTFT screen (none of my Pis use the desktop environment):

```
import os
# Tell the RPi to use the TFT screen and that it's a touchscreen device
os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', 'fbcon')
os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV'      , '/dev/fb1')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDRV'   , 'TSLIB')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDEV'   , '/dev/input/touchscreen')
```

Then you just need to make sure your pi doesn't boot into the desktop environment. You can do that by running:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and changing the relevant setting.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I want to run a PyGame window in fullscreen without booting the whole desktop. You can't run PyGame windows in just the console.

Comment: No, you can't run it in a window, but it can run full screen when called from the command line.  That's what my script does. Put those lines in the top of your pygame program and give it a go.

Comment: If you need to work out the resolution of the screen (because, in my experience, it's not what the manual says) then have a look at [my post on the raspberry pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=52384&p=402524&hilit=+set_mode#p402524)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I really should have tried it before I commented. It works perfectly, resolution and all!